# how to check the php multidimensional array has keys (indexed) or not

Tags: php, api

I'm having an array with some strings in it and I have to show those strings
but sometimes only 1 character has been shown

how to show multidimensional array within foreach loop
for example my array is

$variable['items']['item']

Comment: __Do not post code in comments__. [Edit] it instead.

Comment: what are the values in array `$cs1_array`

Comment: From what you have posted I can't see how that creates the behavior you say. Something must be missing from your question

Answer (score 0):

```
<? foreach ($cs1_array as $key=>$value): ?>
  <hr>
  <p style='color:black;font-size:14px;'><strong>
  <? if($key=='subject') echo $value; ?>
   </strong>
   </p>
  <p style='color:black;font-size:12px;'>
 <? if($key=='Subject') echo $value; ?>
</p>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

also check the $cs1_array maybe is object ,make control with gettype($cs1_array)